# Joystick Constant Disconnecting Problems Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, joystick

I'm trying to get a joystick to work but my device is having problems seeing it.  I will plug in the joystick, it will show up under /dev/input/ but it will disappear after a few seconds, then reappear, and repeat.  Also, I installed the joystick package but js0 never shows up.

When it does show up this is the info I get:

Bus 001 Device 079: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 064: ID 068e:0105 CH Products, Inc.

(This 064 number listed in the last device on this list increments over time since it keeps disconnecting over and over)

root@pc-zed:/dev/input# ls
by-id  by-path  event0  event1  mice  mouse0

root@pc-zed:/dev/input/by-path# ls
platform-xusbps-ehci.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-joystick
platform-xusbps-ehci.0-usb-0:1.2:1.1-event-mouse
platform-xusbps-ehci.0-usb-0:1.2:1.1-mouse

root@pc-zed:/dev/input/by-id# ls
usb-CH_Products_APEM_HF_Joystick-event-joystick
usb-CH_Products_APEM_HF_Joystick-event-mouse
usb-CH_Products_APEM_HF_Joystick-if01-event-mouse
usb-CH_Products_APEM_HF_Joystick-if01-mouse
usb-CH_Products_APEM_HF_Joystick-mouse

The piece of hardware I'm running this on is a ZedBoard with a 3.12.0-xillinux-1.3 kernel
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

I've tried this with a USB hub to ensure this isn't a power issue.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html